# Accordion toggle icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I managed to work out how to change the + icon to - when toggled however you toggle another accordion and the other close it the icon stays - and I wanted to return to + icon.

Was trying to recreate my accordion in jsfiddle but somehow it doesn't work well.
http://jsfiddle.net/13cgkvwg/

or just look at the html mockup [HERE](http://markestrada.co.uk/demos/portfolio/faq)

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function () {
    $("dd.active").find(".content").slideUp("slow");
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
          $(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-minus-circle');
        } else{
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
        }
    // }
});

<section class="faq_accordion">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <dl class="accordion" data-accordion="myAccordionGroup">
              <dd class="accordion-navigation">
                <a href="#panel2">Hosting <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                <div id="panel2" class="content">
                  <p>Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
              </dd>
              <dd class="accordion-navigation">
                <a href="#panel3">Accordion 3 <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                <div id="panel3" class="content">
                  <p>Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
              </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Element doesn't have `active` class so never goes to else. So you have to add `active` class like:

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function () {
    $(this).find(".content").slideUp("slow");//use this here instead of dd.active
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
          $(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-minus-circle');
          $(this).addClass("active");//here add active class
        } else{
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
            $(this).removeClass("active");//and here remove active class
        }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/13cgkvwg/6/)

Comment: Its kinda buggy though, when you open accordion 1 works ok, open 2nd one okay but the 1st one closes it doesn't return the + and its just weird :/ i don't know how to explain it.

Comment: Now 1 won't close when you open the other :/. Also it toggles twice before it closes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/13cgkvwg/10/).

```
$(".accordion").on("click", "dd", function () {
  $("dd.active").find(".content").slideUp("slow");
  if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("slow");
    $("dd").find('i').removeClass('fa fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-minus-circle');
    $("dd").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  } else{
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: isn't that basically similar to what I already have :/ because it does the same thing.

Comment: You can check the fiddle now.

Comment: Yeah. but you forgot remove `.active` class from other `dd` before add `.active` class to clicked `dd`.
And the class name for the icon too.